# Are there any techniques to cooking food when camping in the wild by harnessing the energy of the sun?

Tags: camping, cooking, sun

Are there any techniques to cooking food camping in the wild by harnessing the sun's energy (rays)?

We have all heard of solar panels being used to generate electricity, but are there any techniques that we can use to cook food while camping and thus avoiding the use of a fire to cook with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly, what you are looking for is a **backpacking solar stove**.

Here are some examples.

[SunFlair Solar Oven](http://www.solarcooker-at-cantinawest.com/sunflair_solar_oven.html)

[SOLTAC's CookSack](http://www.soltac.com/)

Or if you really wanted to, you could attempt to [build one yourself](http://www.solarcooker-at-cantinawest.com/build_a_simple_solar_cooker.html).

Comment: Interesting. I'd rather eat cold food than carry a solar stove but mostly hike in the Rockies where it wouldn't be that practical anyway. Colder temps and wind would significantly effect performance. Some other ideas... http://zenstoves.net/Solar.htm